# How to zoom animate entire scene in cocos2d for iphone

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, camera, zooming

How to implement zoom animation for entire scene in cocos2d for iPhone. This should be done by automatically not by the touch interaction.

I have tried with,

```
layer.scale = x ;
```

I wanted to zoom the entire scene in few seconds.

Comment: try runnning a scale action on the scene

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Could you tell how can i implement a scaling action.

Comment: CCScaleTo or CCScaleBy .. it's in the api reference